# create xls with c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xls

Is there any free library for create xls files in asp.net on a server without office?

thanks

Comment: I got a couple of good suggestions on a similar question I asked a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292551/modifying-excel-spreadsheet-with-net

Answer (score 1):

See this codeproject solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/biffcsharp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could also use SpreadsheetML. It is just xml so you could generate it by printing text to a file.

Answer (score 1):

OfficeWriter is another third party tool that can be used for this purpose:

http://www.officewriter.com/trial

It's an API that generates/manipulates XLS/XLSX on a server without office.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free but we use the Aspose Cells tool which is excellent